# Getting a undefined reference to `SWM_Mark_Iteration(int)' error

Tags: gcc, compilation, linker, c++14, linker-errors

I am trying to build a project and while linking the shared object I am getting the error

```
/home/bhowmik/installSoftware/swm/lib/libswm.so: undefined reference to `SWM_Mark_Iteration(int)'
```

The configure file for building the project is

```
mkdir -p /home/bhowmik/installSoftware/codes;
../configure --prefix=/home/bhowmik/installSoftware/codes \
  --with-online=/home/bhowmik/installSoftware/swm \
  --with-boost=/home/bhowmik/buildSoftware/installSoftware/boost \
  CC=mpicc \
  CXX=mpicxx \
  CFLAGS='-g -I/home/bhowmik/installSoftware/swm/include' \
  CXXFLAGS='-g -I/home/bhowmik/installSoftware/swm/include' \
  LDFLAGS='-L/home/bhowmik/lib -L/home/bhowmik/installSoftware/swm/lib' \
  LIBS='-lswm' \
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/bhowmik/installSoftware/argobots/lib/pkgconfig:/home/bhowmik/installSoftware/ross/lib/pkgconfig:/home/bhowmik/installSoftware/swm/lib/pkgconfig;

make clean;
make;
make install;
```

The SWM install directory has three folders include, lib and share, the lib folder has library files `libswm.a  libswm.la  libswm.so  libswm.so.0  libswm.so.0.0.0  pkgconfig`
and include folder for swm has all header files.

My LIBRARY_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH looks like `:/home/bhowmik/buildSoftware/TensorflowC/lib:/home/bhowmik/buildSoftware/installSoftware/graphviz/lib:/home/bhowmik/installSoftware/binutils/lib:/home/bhowmik/installSoftware/libunwind/lib:/home/bhowmik/installSoftware/swm/lib`

Please let me know how can I resolve this issue for linking.